# Sybase : trouble with temporary table in transaction

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm encontering the trouble with sybase 15.0 or 15.5
I 've 2 procedure : a main procedure and a sub procedure.
I call the sub procedure when i 'm in a transaction.
I use temporary table in the sub procedure and can't create it in the transaction.
So I create temporary table in the main procedure and use it in the sub.
Temporary table is only use in sub procedure to update a table.
When i call the main procedure, the table is not update but if i call only the sub procedure (i create temporary table before) the table is update. I don't unerstand where is the trouble.

Somebody have an idea ?

EDIT :

```
create procedure MainProc
as
  create table #tmp1(...)
  create table #tmp2(...)
begin
  ...
  begin tran

    ...

    exec SubProc

    ...

  commit
end


--to compile SubProc
create #tmp1(...)
create #tmp2(...)

create procedure SubProc 
as
begin

insert into table1

insert into #tmp1
insert into #tmp2

update table1
from #tmp1,#tmp2

end
```

If i call `Exec MainProc` table1 is not updated.
But if i create temporary table and call `exec SubProc` table1 is correctly updated.

Comment: Please share your code. Hard to comment without looking at the code

Comment: Sybase is such a generic tag, it's helpful to tag the question with the specific Sybase product you are referring to.  I've gone ahead, and added the [sybase-ase] tag.

Comment: @label55 Code works for me, so the sample it's not enough. Can you give us working problematic code?